# get count of all childs with a specific value in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to get the count of all childs with a specific value.

```
users.orderByChild("isOnline").equalTo("1").
        addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot p1)
                {
                    
                    t(""+p1.getChildrenCount());
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError p1)
                {
                
                }   
            
        });
```

but the problem is there is a unique child among each `users` and `isOnline` childs.

[image: a screenshot of firebase database that describes my example]

Answer (score 1):

The values of your `isOnline` node are numbers, so you need to compare them to a number foo:

```
users.orderByChild("isOnline").equalTo(1)...
```

Comment: thanks, Now how can i know which user is that isOnline refer to?